# Direct2D window doesn't fully render

Tags: c++, windows, direct2d

I've only just started attempting to learn Direct2D and Windows, and have been going through the tutorials they have on MSDN. Most of the code I've written is pretty much hand-copied from their site. I'm on a tutorial module that is an introduction to user input, and the code is mostly the same as the previous module, but the program starts and the window never fully renders; its just a white area including where the nonclient area should have rendered(the top bar, sides and bottom). Below is the code of the main.cpp file:

```
#ifndef UNICODE
#define UNICODE
#endif // !UNICODE

#include <windowsx.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <d2d1.h>
#pragma comment (lib, "d2d1")

#include "BaseWindow.h"

template <class T> void SafeRelease(T **ppT)
{
if(*ppT)
{
    (*ppT)->Release();
    *ppT = NULL;
}
}

class DPIScale
{
static float scaleX;
static float scaleY;

public:
static void Intitialize(ID2D1Factory *pFactory)
{
    FLOAT   dpiX, dpiY;
    pFactory->GetDesktopDpi(&dpiX, &dpiY);
    scaleX = dpiX/96.0f;
    scaleY = dpiY/96.0f;
}

template <typename T>
static D2D1_POINT_2F Pixels_To_DIPs(T x, T y)
{
    return D2D1::Point2F(static_cast<float>(x) / scaleX, static_cast<float>(y)     
 / scaleY);
}
};

float DPIScale::scaleX = 1.0F;
float DPIScale::scaleY = 1.0F;

class MainWindow : public BaseWindow<MainWindow>
{
ID2D1Factory            *pFactory;
ID2D1HwndRenderTarget   *pRenderTarget;
ID2D1SolidColorBrush    *pBrush;
D2D1_ELLIPSE            ellipse;
D2D1_POINT_2F           ptMouse;

HRESULT CreateGraphicsResources();
void    DiscardGraphicsResources();
void    Resize();
void    OnPaint();
void    OnLButtonDown(int pixelX, int pixelY, DWORD flags);
void    OnLButtonUp();
void    OnMouseMove(int pixelX, int pixelY, DWORD flags);

public:

MainWindow() : pFactory(NULL), pRenderTarget(NULL), pBrush(NULL),   
ellipse(D2D1::Ellipse(D2D1::Point2F(), 0, 0)), 
    ptMouse(D2D1::Point2F()) {}

PCWSTR ClassName() const { return L"D2D Drawing Program Class"; }
LRESULT HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);
};

HRESULT MainWindow::CreateGraphicsResources()
{
HRESULT hr = S_OK;
if( pRenderTarget == NULL )
{
    RECT rc;
    GetClientRect(m_hwnd, &rc);

    D2D_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right, rc.bottom);

    hr = pFactory->CreateHwndRenderTarget(
        D2D1::RenderTargetProperties(),
        D2D1::HwndRenderTargetProperties(m_hwnd, size),
        &pRenderTarget
        );

    if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        const D2D1_COLOR_F color = D2D1::ColorF(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        hr = pRenderTarget->CreateSolidColorBrush(color, &pBrush);
    }
}

return hr;
}

void MainWindow::DiscardGraphicsResources()
{
SafeRelease(&pRenderTarget);
SafeRelease(&pBrush);
}

void MainWindow::OnPaint()
{
HRESULT hr = CreateGraphicsResources();
if(SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    PAINTSTRUCT ps;
    BeginPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);

    pRenderTarget->BeginDraw();

    pRenderTarget->Clear(D2D1::ColorF(D2D1::ColorF::White));
    pRenderTarget->FillEllipse(ellipse, pBrush);

    hr = pRenderTarget->EndDraw();
    if(FAILED(hr) || hr == D2DERR_RECREATE_TARGET)
    {
        DiscardGraphicsResources();
    }
    EndPaint(m_hwnd, &ps);
}
}

void MainWindow::Resize()
{
    if (pRenderTarget != NULL)
    {
        RECT rc;
        GetClientRect(m_hwnd, &rc);

        D2D1_SIZE_U size = D2D1::SizeU(rc.right, rc.bottom);

        pRenderTarget->Resize(size);
        InvalidateRect(m_hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
    }
 }

void MainWindow::OnLButtonDown(int pixelX, int pixelY, DWORD flags)
{
SetCapture(m_hwnd);
ellipse.point = ptMouse = DPIScale::Pixels_To_DIPs(pixelX, pixelY);
ellipse.radiusX = ellipse.radiusY = 1.0f;
InvalidateRect(m_hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
}

void MainWindow::OnLButtonUp()
{
ReleaseCapture();
}

void MainWindow::OnMouseMove(int pixelX, int pixelY, DWORD flags)
{
const D2D1_POINT_2F DIPs = DPIScale::Pixels_To_DIPs(pixelX, pixelY);

const float width = (DIPs.x - ptMouse.x) / 2;
const float height = (DIPs.y - ptMouse.y) / 2;
const float x1 = ptMouse.x + width;
const float y1 = ptMouse.y + height;

ellipse = D2D1::Ellipse(D2D1::Point2F(x1, y1), width, height);

InvalidateRect(m_hwnd, NULL, FALSE);
}

int WINAPI wWinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE, PWSTR, int nCmdShow)
{
MainWindow win;

if( !win.Create(L"D2D Drawing Program", WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW) )
{
    return 0;
}

ShowWindow(win.Window(), nCmdShow);

MSG msg = {};

while(GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
{
    TranslateMessage(&msg);
    DispatchMessage(&msg);
}

return 0;
}

LRESULT MainWindow::HandleMessage(UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
switch(uMsg)
{
    case WM_CREATE:
        if(FAILED(D2D1CreateFactory(D2D1_FACTORY_TYPE_SINGLE_THREADED,  
                         &pFactory)))
        {
            return -1;
        }

        // DPIScale::Intitialize(pFactory);
        return 0;

    case WM_DESTROY:
        DiscardGraphicsResources();
        SafeRelease(&pFactory);
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;

    case WM_PAINT:
        OnPaint();
        return 0;

    case WM_SIZE:
        Resize();
        return 0;

    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
        OnLButtonDown(GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam), 
                           (DWORD)wParam);
        return 0;

    case WM_LBUTTONUP:
        OnLButtonUp();
        return  0;

    case WM_MOUSEMOVE:
        OnMouseMove(GET_X_LPARAM(lParam), GET_Y_LPARAM(lParam   
                           (DWORD)wParam);
        return 0;
}
}
```

Please help if you can! I've been over it for like an hour and a half now and couldn't find any inconsistencies.

There is a BaseWindow template class contained in a header file that this code uses to create and register the window class and all of that, but the header file is a direct copy from another program that works fine so I didn't think that it needed to be included.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out myself. Turns out I forgot to return the default windows procedure at the end of the HandleMessage method.